# error empty parameters route() helper function in laravel 6.*

Tags: laravel, url, routes

in laravel version 5.8 when call route() function with empty parameters like this

```
route('post.edit',['post'=>''])
```

don't get error.

but in version 6 i get this error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Missing required parameters for [Route: post.edit] [URI: admin/post/{post}/edit]. (View: /var/www/html/mysite/resources/views/post/list.blade.php)

now how can i generate route() url with null or empty

Comment: Can you put your controller method and rout that contain in web.php

Comment: is it possible to send `empty` or `null` parameter to `edit route` of resource controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is defined to have a parameter, you would have to define it as an optional parameter to be able to generate a URL with the helper:

```
Route::get('post/{post?}/edit', ....)->name('post.edit');
```

Though, I would imagine the URL that is generated won't match to your route. Kinda odd to have an optional parameter in a middle route segment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i use route resources.  How can I do this in route resources.

Comment: you can't ... you would have to define the route yourself  (have the resource exclude  the edit route and define it yourself)... but there is no reason to have a route like this in the first place, that is kinda the point as it won't match to your route even if you generate the URL ... to edit something means you need to have the identifier for it, so the route you are trying to make doesn't make sense